# jquery callback on new image loaded via ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload-event

I m having a function to get the image width and height but that is not responding to the new images being loaded via a ajax call.

The function being -

```
$('img').on('load',function() {
    console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
});
```

but i m adding DOM to the page using ajax call but the above code is not responding to the new images being loaded

My example page being [here in the link](http://nvoids.com/newAlbum.jsp#uid=1&aid=93&imgid=3516) with the console logs.

Regards

Comment: You have to attach the onLoad event when you add the DOM in

Comment: I have edited the question and added the example page

Comment: I think @Andy you should remove the tag "the question may have a answer here"

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya, I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it in this way

```
$("img").one("load", function() {

}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete){
   console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
 }
});
```

**Updated**

```
$("div.albumList").on("load","img", function() {
      console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);

  });
```

Comment: nope this does not help, i m getting 0x0

Comment: can you add your html part as well?

Comment: I have edited my question with the example page.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is to be done as said by [Rafael Diaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908080/jquery-callback-on-new-image-loaded-via-ajax-call#comment38696903_24908080)

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'bAlbum.jsp',
        data: null ,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('ol#imagelist').append(html);               

            $("ol#imagelist li").each( function (i, e)
            {

               $(e).find('img').one('load', function() {
                   console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
               });
            });
        }
    });
```